# Saving displayed values on the command window - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, save

I had a GUI to collect all data and to save it when I clicked a button. It displays a graph with all the data it collects. Unfortunately after collecting data for over 2 hours, it stopped. The data was 'precious'.

I don't know of any way to recover the data, but all of it was displayed in the command window. Is there a way I can retrieve all the data from the command window? Does MATLAB have a cache with all the values which I can access?

Comment: You might be able to copy and paste it into a script as an array

Answer (score 0):

As long as matlab itself, (and the console in particular) is still responsive, you can just copy and paste everything out of the buffer into any text editor.  Then, you can do a few minor edits, to get it into a text matlab input file, and you're good to go.  Or if you've formatted your output correctly, you could put it into a text file, and read it in using readtable.

The key issue here, is how much memory do you have in your console window?  I'm sure that can be tweaked up large, but did you bother to do that before you started running your GUI.

Note:  In the future, always dump data to a log file as soon as it's collected!  I've learned this lesson many times, the hard way.